# Как добавить эти `` сверху

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно добавить верхние скобочки ``
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так скобочки или [кавычки](https://symbl.cc/ru/collections/quotation-marks/) типа ❝ ❞ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/left-double-quotation-mark/)

```html
<span style="font-size:500%;float:left">&ldquo;</span>
<span style="float:left;margin:15px">Бла-бла-бла</span>
<span style="font-size:500%;float:left">&rdquo;</span>
```